# GETH // Stopping work on payload reason=timeout // is this standard behaviour?

Tags: go-ethereum, logs

I am currently running a node via the rocketpool docker, with geth and Prysm as my clients.

I noticed relatively recently, perhaps since Shapella, that all my 'Stopping work on payload' notifications were due to a timeout.

I searched around and didn't find much information on that specific log. So I guess it's not an issue, but I do prefer to ask here since I'm on the verge of launching a validator and want everything to be neat and tidy.

And also for education purposes, what's the difference between *reason=delivery* and *reason=timeout* ?

Thanks alot.